# Eclipse luna no field name completion?

Tags: eclipse

I'm currently using eclipse luna which works very nicely.

In eclipse kepler i could do the following:

```
private VoteService vote(press CTRL+SPACE)
```

after CTRL+SPACE was pressed i would get a little menu and i could pick "voteService". The result would be:

```
private VoteService voteService
```

Now i only get a little menu like:

[image]

As you can see the "voteService" item is missing. I suspect this is called "field name completion" or something similar. All other completions work as normal.

How can i get the "field name completion" to work again? I got a bit lost while wandering through the content assist options :)
(i've enabled (as test) all the proposal kinds in content assist > advanced but still don't have field/variable name completion)

[update]
It seems to work in a a method body. Strangely enough it doesn't work for class variables, for example:

```
public class Burb {
private VoteService vote(CTRL+SPACE)
```

Comment: Check your settings in Preferences-Java-Editor-Content Assist-Advanced

Comment: What happens when you Ctrl+Click `VoteService`? Do you see an error in the status bar?

Comment: @Joachim i quote from my original post "(i've enabled (as test) all the proposal kinds in content assist > advanced but still don't have field/variable name completion)"

Comment: @AaronDigulla gave it a shot ;) Eclipse sends me to the VoteService class.

Comment: Seems to be an eclipse luna bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=441978 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=438446. It happens if field is annotated. Unfortunately there is no fix for this problem. Workaround: first declare the field, then annotate it...

Comment: Cheers @Lotzy , that explains it. Waiting patiently for the next eclipse update.

Comment: Meanwhile if the above workaround is not working, just type semicolon then position cursor before semicolon and then CTRL+SPACE, example:

private VoteService ;

Comment: @Lotzy Thanks for the semicolon trick. The other workaround -not annotating the field doesn't work as annotations on other fields also blocks name proposal. Unfortunately the bug is still there in Eclipse Mars.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Lotzy mentioned in the comments, it's an Eclipse bug, it appeared in Eclipse Luna, it's still around in Eclipse Mars and the workaround is typing the semicolon first:

> just type semicolon then position cursor before semicolon and then CTRL+SPACE

Answer (score 0):

In my case; Window>Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced

Make sure Select the proposal>Template Proposals,SWT Template Proposals,Java Proposals ,Content assist cycling>Template Proposals,SWT Template Proposals,Java Proposals is ticked.